# Хранятся ли аргументы функции в какой-то переменной?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=5
b=6
def func(a, b)
    for arg in args:
        print(arg) #5 6
```

Есть ли какая-то переменная, которая похожа на мною выдуманную args?

Comment: Думаю да, print() называется

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato, я спросил про переменную, а не про функцию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте функцию [locals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals), выдающую словарь локальных переменных:

```py
def func(a, b):
    print(locals())

func(5, 6)
```

Вывод:

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 6}
```

Это обычный словарь. Если вам нужны только значения, а названия переменных не нужны, возьмите из словаря `values`:

```
print(*locals().values()) # 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

При вызове функции, на место параметра **args** передается список аргументов, который можно потом использовать:

```
a=5
b=6
def func(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)

func(a,b)
```

Comment: Допустим вместо *args я хочу взять **kwargs. Можно ли сделать аннотацию для каждого аргумента в **kwargs?

Comment: @СашаГоголь только общую аннотацию для значений kwargs. Тут только два варианта: отдельные аргументы с возможностью указать разные аннотации на каждый аргумент, либо args/kwargs.

Comment: @Саша Гоголь, если в кратце: *args - используется для передачи/принятия списка; ** **kwargs** - используется для передачи/принятия словаря. Причем их можно одновременно использовать.